# Receive delivery message from SMSC InteLab SMPP

Tags: c#, .net, sms, smpp, inetlab.smpp

I have tried this weeks and still I couldn't figure out how to get delivery messages after sent SMS from SMSC. I have used Intelab SMPP and developed a sms system. I have used following codes to get Delivery receipt and I got the receipt successfully with MessageId.

```
public static IList<SubmitSmResp> ConnectToInet(string sourceAddress, string DestinationAddress, string Message)
    {
        try
        {
            SmppClient client = new SmppClient();
            IList<SubmitSmResp> respList = null;
            client.Connect(#SMSSeverIP, #PORT);

            if (client.Status == Inetlab.SMPP.Common.ConnectionStatus.Open)
            {
                client.Bind("USERNAME", "Password", Inetlab.SMPP.Common.ConnectionMode.Transceiver);

                if (client.Status == Inetlab.SMPP.Common.ConnectionStatus.Bound)
                {
                    client.AddrTon = 5;

                    respList = client.Submit(
                        SMS.ForSubmit().From(sourceAddress).To(DestinationAddress).Text(Message).DeliveryReceipt().Coding(DataCodings.Default)
                        );


                    //client.Submit(SMS.ForSubmit().Text(Message).From(sourceAddress).To(DestinationAddress).DeliveryReceipt().Coding(DataCodings.Default));

                    client.evDeliverSm += new Inetlab.SMPP.Common.DeliverSmEventHandler(OnDeliverSm);




                    client.UnBind();
                }

                client.Disconnect();
            }
            return respList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

And I the DeliverSm method is using to get delivery receipt which I have able to receive delivery receipt successfully.

```
private static void OnDeliverSm(object sender, DeliverSm data)
    {
        string messageText = data.Client.GetMessageText(data.UserDataPdu.ShortMessage, data.DataCoding);
    }
```

I have stored the received MessageId from each SMSC response and I need to use it to get the corresponding delivery report of each message with delivery status, delivered date and submitted date. Can someone help me to figure this out. Thank you for the help!

Comment: As I see, you unbind immediately after setting SMPP delivery handler, maybe this is a reason you don;t receive DR. Try to wait for some time before unbind.

Comment: I had an improvement with you Idea but still I dont getting the result. I'm getting only messageId value issued from SMSC and NONE as the status. no submitDate and DoneDate. and I need to get delivery messages after some time of sending the SMS by using stored messageId. Im using windows service to it and cannot implement evDeliverSm event inside the windows service. do you have any Idea about that? thank you for the response by the way.

Comment: Check the DR message (short_message or payload_message), usually SMSC put statuses and times within that field, otherwise SMSC may not be configured properly for Application DR delivery. And before that, start Wireshark to see if your DR PDU has all fields you need.

Comment: My SMSC has configured properly and still I have figureout what the problem is. Although I haven't unbound the client the OnDeliverSm method is not firing. Is any error in my code? when I debugged the code OnDeliverSm method never get called.

Comment: What is submit status (resp), is it successfull ?
What is response from Deliver registration event ?
Did you check wireshark see DeliverSM packet ?
Which SMSC do you use ?

Comment: I have found a solution. I cannot install wireshark without permission because I'm working on a remote computer. So I tried severel things. after debugged my wcf service I found that my OnDeliverSm is not firing. I had to remove both client.Disconnect() and client.Unbind() and moved the    `client.evDeliverSm += new Inetlab.SMPP.Common.DeliverSmEventHandler(OnDeliverSm);` just before the if statement after cliend.Bound() is called. Now I'm getting delivery report inside my event onDeliverSm. Thank you for the help! your tip of remove unbind for some time helped me!